# html global attributes React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-deployment

I apologize if this is a silly question, but maybe legitimate for the web developer newbie.

So I understand that a backend server serves HTML where the code is in the clients browser to render. With [global HTML attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp) I am learning that I can set an attribute `contentEditable="true"` in react and then in the browser I can edit the text.

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" contentEditable="true">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am learning in code sand box with React. Is it possible on the client side browser to be able to change/edit the text in the html file and then for the server to save that data? So when the client closes the browser and then opens another session, that the changed edited text is present in the HTML file that was served by the server?

If it is possible to do something like this what would all go into this process explained a a high level for the newb to understand? Anything React related also greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No question is silly!!!

Yes, you can do it all you need is an API to update and save at the server.
You have maintain a backend where you can store/update all the user data and serve when user comes at your website.

Comment: Would you know of any links to look at or tutorials? I am using React and Python backend servers. SO my react code would need to like POST to my backend Python server which would update the HTML file somehow? How does that work?

Comment: Are you maintaining Backend by yourself?

Comment: Yes my backend skills are much more developed that front end. I am learning front end so setting up an API for the backend is something I definitely understand.